# What type of film is "GAF Type 2005" film?

Tags: film, 35mm

I recently came across these, and bought some to experiment.

[image]
[image]

<sub>*Photos courtesy of the seller*</sub>

All the can reads is

> "GAF Corporation.  Open in total darkness.  Recording Type 2005."

Unfortunately the internet doesn't seem to have much on this - I'd love to know what ISO, color or type of film it is before shooting it.

Comment: This resource: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7227224 at least groups a couple of their film offerings for an expo. Its order appears to go: specialty, color slide, "recording film". That probably narrows it down to color negative or black and white. They used C-22 back then, so there's that as well.

Comment: If you've got a bunch, it'd be best to burn a roll shooting a constant object at varying ISO's from, probably 12 on up (12,25,50,100). Include half stops if you like. Develop as black and white and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Black & White Super Hypan 500 ISO
Quite outdated - Why bother using - maybe best to send to a museum.
GAF (General Aniline & Film) Binghamton NY. Emerged from bankruptcy now making roofing supplies.

Comment: "Why bother using" because it's fun to try new things!  I like expressing my vision in different chemical types... this will definitely be the first time I use 500 iso! Not very common

Comment: Hi Alan. Where did you get this information that GAF Recording Film Type 2005 = Black & White Super Hypan 500 ISO?

Comment: Doesn't tell me what process it uses...

Comment: @MicroMachine the process is for B&W negative film as Alan mentioned. You'll never know what the actual ISO is now after it has aged. Figure that a more practical index would be somewhere between 100 and 250. As well, unless you have a supply of this stock, your experiments will not be applicable to other more recent material. Expect some fogging in the end of the roll nearest the opening.